# Error importing configuration

Tags: configuration

[error] Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.

```
The <em class="placeholder">language.content_settings.media.instagram</em> setting depends on the <em class="placeholder">media.type.instagram</em> setting which will not exist after import.
The <em class="placeholder">medical_network.settings</em> setting depends on the <em class="placeholder">medical_network</em> extension which will not be installed after importing.
The <em class="placeholder">SettingsEmalForm.settings</em> setting depends on the <em class="placeholder">SettingsEmalForm</em> extension which will not be installed after import. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 756 of /app/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).
```

Maybe someone has an idea on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the error message already. Let me translate:

> Your config folder contains a `medical_network.settings.yml` but your `core.extension.yml` does not contain an entry for the `medical_network` module.

Same for the `SettingsEmalForm` module, which sounds custom and wrong naming (you must only use lower case letters and underscores for module machine names) plus typo "Emal" instead of `_email_`.

And some media type `media.type.instagram` was not exported. But there's config that relies on it.

Fix it by getting a live database and exporting config once. Then restart whatever you were doing, fix naming and typos and export config again before you commit it.